# GWT CellList Horizontal

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Does anybody know how to make a CellList oriented horizontally? If possible, please with UiBinder, but this is not necessary.

Comment: Did you ever get a good answer for this?

Comment: @slugmandrew - Hopefully the answer to your question is now "yes" :-) See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25568087/685715

Comment: Amazing that I asked that question 2 years ago, you replied one year ago, and here I am back here now making use of it :) Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Following Thomas Broyer's suggestion [on the google-web-toolkit group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/rPfCO5H91Rk), and [How to style GWT CellList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700458/how-to-style-gwt-celllist), we can inject a new CSS resource into the CellList constructor.

The CSS for getting the horizonltal formatting `MyCellList.css`:

```
/* This file is based on the CSS for a GWT CellList:
 * https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/master/./user/src/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellList.css
 * The primary purpose is to arrange for the <div> elements that contain each cell to be laid out inline (horizontally).
 */

/* Using inline-block, following Thomas Broyer's recommendations (with link to justification) here:
 * https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/rPfCO5H91Rk
 */
.cellListEvenItem {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}

.cellListOddItem {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Define a new Resource like this:

```
public interface MyCellListResource extends CellList.Resources {
  public static MyCellListResource INSTANCE = GWT.create(MyCellListResource.class);
  interface MyCellListStyle extends CellList.Style {}

  @Override
  @Source({CellList.Style.DEFAULT_CSS, "MyCellList.css"})
  MyCellListStyle cellListStyle();
}
```

Inject the new style, and pass it CellList's constructor:

```
    MyCellListResource.INSTANCE.cellListStyle().ensureInjected();

    CellList<Fare> cellList = new CellList<Fare>(cell, MyCellListResource.INSTANCE);
```

Note that the new style appears in the cascade after the DEFAULT style for CellList, so you need only put the modifications you require into your MyCellList.css.

Answer (score 1):

Try to override the CellList.renderRowValues method. You have to be able to create a horizontal presentation template.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of logic in that method I didn't want to reproduce, but my hacky solution of just replacing all div's with span's worked:

```java
public class HorizontalCellList<T> extends CellList<T> {

  public HorizontalCellList(Cell<T> cell) {
    super(cell);
  }

  @Override
  protected void renderRowValues(
      SafeHtmlBuilder sb, List<T> values, int start, SelectionModel<? super T> selectionModel) {
    SafeHtmlBuilder filteredSB = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
    super.renderRowValues(filteredSB, values, start, selectionModel);
    SafeHtml safeHtml = filteredSB.toSafeHtml();
    String filtered = safeHtml.asString().replaceAll("<div", "<span").replaceAll("div>","span>");
    sb.append(SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(filtered));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A variant with CSS - set CSS class name on you cell list

```
CellList<T> list = new CellList<T>(...);
list.addStyleName('myList');
```

then apply CSS rule to the cells to make them align horizontally:

```
.myList > div > div > div {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to solve this by extending CellList and creating my own template + overriding the renderRowValues method. Simply changing divs into spans didn't do the trick for me maybe it was because I have custom cells (each cell is rendered as table). Adding display:inline on the CSS didn't work for me also.

My template code is pretty much the same as the original except I added the "float:left;" style:

```
    interface Template extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
    @Template("<div onclick=\"\" __idx=\"{0}\" style=\"float:left;\">{1}</div>")
    SafeHtml span(int idx, SafeHtml cellContents); ...
```

Here's a snippet of my renderRowValue method:

```
    int length = values.size();
    int end = start + length;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        SingleKeyValueModel value = values.get(i - start);

        //super.renderRowValues(sb, values, start, selectionModel);

        SafeHtmlBuilder cellBuilder = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
        Context context = new Context(i, 0, getValueKey(value));
        cell.render(context, value, cellBuilder);


        sb.append(TEMPLATE.span(i, cellBuilder.toSafeHtml()));

    }
```