# How to style GWT CellList?

Tags: gwt, gwt2, gwt-2.4

I have a CellList that I want to style. I want to change the cursor style, the ugly color of a selected cell . I checked several questions and discussions on stack overflow,but none of them worked.
I checked these one:

[CellList GWT CSS Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636192/celllist-gwt-css-style)

[How do I style a gwt 2.1 CellTables headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194717/how-do-i-style-a-gwt-2-1-celltables-headers)

Her is my code:

```
public interface CellListResource extends CellList.Resources {


  public static CellListResource INSTANCE = GWT.create(CellListResource.class);

  interface CellListStyle extends CellList.Style {

  }

  @Source({CellList.Style.DEFAULT_CSS, "CellTableStyle.css"})
  CellListStyle style();
}

 public SearchViewImpl() {

    CompanyCell companyCell = new CompanyCell();
//it doesn't work :S 
    companiesList = new CellList<Company>(companyCell, CellListResource.INSTANCE);

    rootElement = ourUiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);

    loadingImage.setVisible(false);
  }
```

Am I missing something? I Cleared Browser cache, Restarted server, F5 F5 F5  .... F5 (pressed refresh again and again) and nothing ...! 
Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you inject the css resource.

```
CellTableResources.INSTANCE.cellTableStyle().ensureInjected();
myCellTable = new CellTable<T>(Integer.MAX_VALUE,CellTableResources.INSTANCE);
```

You can follow the following link

[How do you change the mouse over highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993918/how-do-you-change-the-mouse-over-highlighting)

Answer (score 3):

Besides injecting the CSS it's important that you call the CellListStyle style cellListStyle() and not just style():

```
public interface CellListResource extends CellList.Resources {
  public static CellListResource INSTANCE = GWT.create(CellListResource.class);
  interface CellListStyle extends CellList.Style {}

  @Override
  @Source("cellListStyle.css")
  CellListStyle cellListStyle();
}
```

and then you do

```
CellListResource.INSTANCE.cellListStyle().ensureInjected();
companiesList = new CellList<Company>(companyCell, CellListResource.INSTANCE);
```

Comment: I wondered why it is important to call the method `cellListStyle()` and not `style()`. This comment is for you if you wonder similarly. The clue is in the `@Override` annotation: you need to override the method of that name in `CellList.Resources`.