# How can i apply the custom style to DatePicker from the CssResources class?

Tags: gwt-2.5

I have a DatePicker widget for which i need to apply the custom styles for it. To achive it, what i have done is, in applications main css file, I have added the css styles as below

```
.dRPLable {
     font-size: 10px;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: gray;
    }

    .dRPBtn {
     background-color: #38B0DE;
     background: #38B0DE;
     color: white;
    }

    .dRPLB {
     background: #EEEEEE;
    }

    .dRPPopup {
        width: 8em;
        height: 2em;
    }
    .mycal .datePickerPreviousButton { visibility: visible; color: gray; }
    .mycal .datePickerNextButton { visibility: visible; color: gray; }

    .mycal .datePickerWeekdayLabel{background: white;}
    .mycal .datePickerMonthSelector {  background: white; }
    .mycal .datePickerMonth { background: white;color: orange;}

    .mycal .datePickerWeekendLabel{background: white;}
    .mycal .datePickerDayIsValue {  background: orange;}
    .mycal .datePickerDayIsWeekend { background: #D9D9D9;}
```

**Then everything is applying perfectly**

I am making it as a independent custom widget, for that i have created a separate css file.
To access it I have created a resources interface as below,

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.ClientBundle;
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.CssResource;
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.ImageResource;

public interface DateRangeTypePickerResources extends ClientBundle {

    DateRangeTypePickerResources INSTANCE = GWT
            .create(DateRangeTypePickerResources.class);

    /*
     * @Source("DocumentImg.jpg") ImageResource getDocumentImg();
     */

    @Source("down.png")
    ImageResource getDownImg();

    @Source("up.png")
    ImageResource getUpImg();

    public interface DateRangeTypePickerCssStyle extends CssResource {
        String dRPLable();

        String dRPBtn();

        String dRPLB();

        String mycal();

        String dRPPopup();

        String datePickerPreviousButton();

        String datePickerNextButton();

        String datePickerWeekdayLabel();

        String datePickerWeekendLabel();

        String datePickerMonthSelector();

        String datePickerMonth();

        String datePickerDayIsValue();

        String datePickerDayIsWeekend();

    }

    @Source("../widget/DateRangeTypePicker.css")
    DateRangeTypePickerCssStyle DateRangeTypePickerCss();

}
```

**How i am accessing those methods as below**

```
public class DateRangePicker extends Composite {
static DateRangeTypePickerResources resources = GWT
            .create(DateRangeTypePickerResources.class);
    DateRangeTypePickerCssStyle css = DateRangeTypePickerResources.INSTANCE
            .DateRangeTypePickerCss();
    static {
        DateRangeTypePickerResources.INSTANCE.DateRangeTypePickerCss()
                .ensureInjected();
    }

public DateRangePicker(DateRangePickerModel dateRangePickerModel) {
    Label startDateLabel = new Label("Start Date");
    startDtToday.setStylePrimaryName(css.dRPLabel());
    flexTable.setWidget(0, 0, startDateLabel);

    DatePicker startDatePicker = new DatePicker();
    startDatePicker.setStyleName(css.mycal());
}
}
```

Here style is applying for Label. But Style is not applying for DatePicker.
How can i apply the custom style to DatePicker from the CssResources class?

Answer (score 1):

Before posting such a huge and repeated question search if the question is already asked or not... There are many similar question to it.

And the answer for your question is in the following link

[ClickHere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700458/how-to-style-gwt-celllist/13577567#13577567)